# How to separate a column into two columns

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,2,3,4),
                 CODE=c('N18','N180','N190','M1920'))
```

I want to separate the variable 'CODE' into two variables. One variable shows the first letter of 'CODE' ('N' or 'M' in my case), the other shows the left number. If there are more than two digits, give a '.' after the second digit.

The output should be

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,2,3,4),
                 CODE=c('N18','N180','N190','M1920'),
                 VOR_1=c('N','N','N','M'),
                 VOR_2=c('18','18.0','19.0','19.20'))
```

Finally, define the variable of 'VOR_2' as a numeric variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub` for a base R solution:

```
df$VOR_1 <- sub("^([A-Z]).*$", "\\1", df$CODE)
df$VOR_2 <- sub("^([0-9]{2})(?=[0-9])", "\\1.", sub("^[A-Z]([0-9]+)$", "\\1", df$CODE), perl=TRUE)
df$VOR_2 <- as.numeric(df$VOR_2)    # if desired
df

PATIENT_ID  CODE VOR_1 VOR_2
1          1   N18     N    18
2          2  N180     N  18.0
3          3  N190     N  19.0
4          4 M1920     M 19.20
```

An explanation on the logic behind `VOR_2` is warranted.  We first extract all the digits from the second character onwards using the simple regex `^[A-Z]([0-9]+)$`.  Then, we make a second call to `sub` on the digit string, to insert a decimal point after the second digit.  The pattern uses a positive lookahead which ensures that a dot gets intercolated only in the case of *three* or more digits.

Comment: when I define VOR_2 as numeric variable, the values become 18.0, 18.0, 19.0 and 19.2

Comment: Can I ask what does '\\1.' and '\\1' mean? Thank you!

Comment: @Franky Yes...that's because zeroes to the right of non zero digits right of the decimal point are not _significant_, and therefore R won't display them.  Do you want a numeric column, or do you want to _view_ your data this way?  `\\1` is a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

An idea via `tidyr` using `separate` can be,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #separate

df %>%
     separate(CODE, into = c("text", "num"), sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
     mutate(num = as.numeric(num),
            num = num / (10 ^ (nchar(num) - 2))
            )

#  PATIENT_ID text  num
#1          1    N 18.0
#2          2    N 18.0
#3          3    N 19.0
#4          4    M 19.2
```

Comment: I almost feel like the OP actually _doesn't_ want to convert `VOR_2` to numeric, but let's wait for feedback.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Indeed. Haven't notice that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't want it to be numeric. They should be 18,18.0,19.0 and 19.20. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` and `sub`:

```
library(stringr)
df$VOR1 <- str_extract(df$CODE, "^[A-Z]")
```

Here, you simply grasp the capicatl letter at the beginning of the string marked by `^`.

```
df$VOR2 <- sub("(\\d{2})(\\d{1,2})", "\\1.\\2", str_extract(df$CODE, "\\d+"))
```

Here, you first extract just the digits using `str_extract` and then insert the period `.`where appropriate:

Result:

```
df
  PATIENT_ID  CODE VOR1  VOR2
1          1   N18    N    18
2          2  N180    N  18.0
3          3  N190    N  19.0
4          4 M1920    M 19.20
```